# Getting a negative NaN on g++ 4.4.3, is this standard?

Tags: c++, math, gcc, floating-point, g++

I have g++ 4.4.3 on Linux with Ubuntu Lucid Lynx, and I am getting a:

-nan

as a result.  On Hardy Heron with g++ 4.3.1, I am getting all

nan

This is causing my text diff regression to fail, since I am using cout to print this numerical result.

What is the meaning of a signed nan, and is there a way to tell the compiler that an unsigned nan is sufficient?

Comment: What calculation are you doing that results in such a value?

Comment: What do you mean by "signed nan"?  Do you mean negative?  Taking a quick look at the Wikipedia article, NaNs are explicitly signed.

Comment: "cout << 0./0. << endl" results is "-nan" on all my Ubuntu Lucid Lynx Systems, and "nan" on Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Ubuntu Hardy Heron.  These are all x86_64 systems.

Comment: What is the assembly difference? can you give the -S dump?

Comment: It turns out this is a change in glibc, and not in the compiler itself.  Running the identical binary on different machines yields different results, since the system glibc is different.  This is described below by Matthew Slattery.

Comment: Juan - you should mark Matthew Slattery's answer as accepted.  Click the checkmark icon next to the answer.

Answer (score 13):

The change in behaviour may be due to libraries rather than the compiler.  There is certainly a change in glibc around the right sort of time - from the entry for 2009-08-23 at line 2528 in `ChangeLog.17` in the glibc source:

```
...
     * stdio-common/printf_fp.c: ISO C expects to print the sign of NaN
     as well.
...
```

Comment: Incredible find.  The exact same binary copied to the newer machine results in the -nan.  Excellent work!

Comment: Actually, ISO C _doesn't_ expect to print the sign, it's left as implementation-dependent. Don't let me detract from your answer though, it was a good find, and no doubt the reason why the behaviour changed.

Comment: Matthew Slattery How did you manage to find that line which was quite undiscoverable ?

Answer (score 8):

You *can* get a signed NaN since the NaN-ness of the value and the sign of the value are controlled by different bits in IEEE754 (NaN is simply indicated by special exponent values, distinct from the sign bit). I'm at a loss as to what sort of operation would do it though.

It's *possible* that one of the normal operations that produce NaN could be causing a negative variation (like `+0/-0` or `+Inf/-Inf`). But I would have thought that NaNs would print as `nan` regardless of sign.

However, while the standard specifies in great detail how numbers are handled, it's strangely silent on how they're printed. The [Wikipedia page for NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) lists these:

```
nan         NaN         NaN%        NAN         NaNQ
NaNS        qNaN        sNaN        1.#SNAN     1.#QNAN
-1.#IND     -NaN        NaN12345    -sNaN12300
```

with some of those showing sign and the extra payload.

Note that I'm talking about the IEEE standards here. The ISO C standards do indicate a limited number of forms but whether the sign and/or payload is printed is implementation-dependent. I can only assume that the later versions of the library have changed their behaviour.

How to fix it within the compiler, I'm not sure. I'd just take the pragmatic approach and run your output file through something like `sed 's/-nan/nan/g'`. Hopefully that won't introduce other problems.

And you should also keep an eye on the form that allows the payload to be printed as well, though I'd only worry about that when the tests start failing again. But I'd put a comment somewhere near that `sed` command indicating that it may happen at some time in the future. That way, at least the guy that follows you will understand why.

Comment: I can filter the result, but I just want to make sure my reasoning is legitimate when someone sees the filtering.

Comment: The standard itself defines it as NaN when exponent is the max value and mantissa is of a certain format. Sign doesn't come into it. I would simply chalk it up to simplistic output routine that checked the sign regardless of whether it was outputting a real numbers or one of the specials.

Answer (score 2):

Signed NaN is possible, though I don't know enough about floating point to know why one platform would produce -NaN and another would produce NaN.  But since NaN has some unusual behaviors, I'm really not surprised that that could happen.

Here's a snippet from the C99 document description for formatted floating point I/O:

> A double argument representing a NaN
>   is converted in one of the styles
>   [-]nan or [-]nan(n-char-sequence) —
>   which style, and the meaning of any
>   n-char-sequence, is
>   implementation-defined. The F
>   conversion specifier

You can use `copysign()` to get the sign of a NaN value. An example from the C99 document:

```
if (isnan(c)) c = copysign(0.0, c);
```

But [as paxdiablo indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772835/getting-a-signed-nan-on-g-4-4-3-is-this-standard/3772902#3772902), it might be easier to allow for the "-nan" result in your test scripts.